# How do you change the background color of a Button in Android using the Holo Theme?

Tags: android, themes, android-3.0-honeycomb

While working on an Android app, I came across this problem.  I can't change the style of a button while using the Android 3.0 Holo Theme.

In my theme.xml file is this:

```
 <resources>
     <style name="Test" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
     </style>
 </resources>
```

My manifest.xml file has this:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/my_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false" android:theme="@style/Test">
```

If I run the app at this point, I get the default Holo themed buttons.  But I want to change the color of them.  It seems like it's a transparency issue, but I'm not sure where to look.

I've tried creating a custom button style.  Something simple like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@android:color/black" />
        <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@android:color/white" />
        <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/white" />
        <item android:color="#f8f8f8" />
    </selector>
```

This doesn't work for me though.  Every combination I've tried doesn't work.

I know that it must be inheriting some property that's making it transparent, but I have no idea which one.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try using android:drawable instead of android:color.

e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@android:color/black" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:drawable="#f8f8f8" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since a button does have a background drawable you can tint this background drawable. It has to be noted though that this background is semi transparent so the tint will not bee 100%. This looks pretty nice on the Holot dark theme though.

Here is how you do it:

```
Drawable bgDrawable = button.getBackground();

ColorMatrix cmDesat = new ColorMatrix();
cmDesat.setSaturation( 0 );
ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
cm.set( new float[]{
  r, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, g, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, b, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 1, 0
} );
cmDesat.postConcat( cm );
bgDrawable.setColorFilter( new ColorMatrixColorFilter( cmDesat ) );
```

Try experimenting with the matrix as it can yield different results. Also instead of the ColorMatrixColorFilter you could simply use the LightingColorFilter which is easier to handle but not as flexible.